# How does this recursive permutation generator work?

Tags: python, recursion, generator, permutation

I'm having trouble understanding this code used to find permutations. The code works

```
def permute2(seq):
    if not seq:   # Shuffle any sequence: generator
        yield seq # Empty sequence
    else:
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            rest = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:] # Delete current node
            for x in permute2(rest):   # Permute the others
                # In some cases x = empty string
                yield seq[i:i+1] + x   # Add node at front

for x in permute2('abc'):
    print('result =', x)
```

When yielding the first result (`'abc'`) the value of `seq` is `'abc'`.
Flow of control takes it back to the top of the outer for loop where `i` now is 1, which makes sense, however the value of `seq` is now `'bc'` which completely baffles me.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger, or write the variables down on paper and execute it by hand.

Comment: PyCharm is free and has an excellent debugger, which you can use to step through your code line by line. Here is how to use the debugger once you install PyCharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html

Comment: @mkrieger1 `seq` is '`bc'` in the first recursion.

Comment: OP, flow control never went back to the outer loop. This is a recursive function, so when you did `rest = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]`, in the first iteration `rest = 'bc'`. Then, you did `for x in permute2(rest)`, and the first element in that iteration is `'bc'` because the function yields whatever it received right away